# Regarding OAS lpu test answer find

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to know by doing inspect during OAS lpu test how can I find the answer of question. Under which tag it is available ???

I open the OAS lpu test , start the test , right click , go to inspect and click that . After this help answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The answers will not be available to you, no matter how good of a sleuth you are.

If this website was made well, the answers to the test will not be stored on the front end of the page: they will only be on the webpage's back end, which is inaccessible to you as a user. It would be a major security flaw to have the answers for an online test stored in the front end code (which is the code that you can see if you "inspect" the page).

Comment: Under which tag there the answer lie

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I would guess that the test answers don't exist under any HTML tags (unless this is a poorly made website). The purpose of this site, I imagine, is to test students. If there was a student who could cheat by simply inspecting the elements on the page, then they would have an unfair advantage, and the website would not be doing its job. It is very easy for coders to only put answers in the HTML for admins, or to students when they are done with the test.

Comment: U know how to find the answer from backend , if u know help me

Comment: Nobody can see the backend code besides the developers who made the website. To see the backend, you would have to know the developer's password to a Github or AWS account, or wherever the code is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answers aren't stored in the html pages it is stored in the backend of the oas server and it can be accessible if you are into the cybersecurity thing . I have found the vulnerability in the site of viewing the answers you can exploit it . I am not going the share the full detail of the process but i can give you the hint . The answers are stored under the /EditQuestionMaster page which is not accessible to the normal user unless you are developer or Hacker . by accessing the page you can get the answers of any exams that are going to be conducted on the oas .[image: Oas answers image]    And in case if you are wondering what tool i am using here . well its Burpsuite